# O hover não está funcionando. Por quê?

Tags: css-hover

```css
@charset "utf-8";
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 50px;
}


/* Formatação de imagens com legendas */

figure.foto-legenda {
  position: relative;
  border: 8px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

figure.foto-legenda img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 1s;
}

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: adicione as imagens também. Tente fazer um código funcional para testarmos. Você pode adicionar um snippet usando Ctrl + M

Comment: Seria bom vc incluir o seu HTML tb na pergunta. Não está funcionando em que sentido? O que é o problema mais precisamente?

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, a opacidade está setada como 1, que é o padrão para os elementos. Sendo assim nesse trecho do código:

```
figure.foto-legenda figcaption{
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
        color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        padding: 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        transition: opacity 1s;
        opacity: 0; //deixando com opacidade 0.
}
```

Se você implementar uma opacidade abaixo de 1, provavelmente surtiria algum efeito!

Answer (score 2):

Se vc quer que o elemento faça a transição de opacidade de 0 para 1 primeiro vc tem que declarar ele com `opacity:0` na classe `figure.foto-legenda figcaption`. 
E quando vc fizer o `:hover` a transição da opacidade vai acontecer indo para `opacity:1` na classe `figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption`.

Resumindo para ter a transição no `:hover` o primeiro estado do elemento deve ser `opacity:0`, deixei o comentário no código.

Veja funcionando no exemplo:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

body {
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
}
p{
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 50px;

}

/* Formatação de imagens com legendas */

figure.foto-legenda{
  position: relative;
  border: 8px solid white;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;

}

figure.foto-legenda img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: opacity 1s;
  opacity: 0; /* primeir vc seta a opacidade como 0, pois o padrão é 1 */
}
figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption
{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda ">
  <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor.</p>
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" alt="">
  <figcaption>Miniatura da torre Eiffel no Parque Mini-France</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: Me ganhou... :D

Answer (score 2):

Tentei simular o HTML que você não postou, e pude notar que a única coisa que faltou foi você inicializar o `opacity` do elemento com:

```
opacity: 0;
```

```css
/* Formatação de imagens com legendas */

figure.foto-legenda {
    position: relative;
    border: 8px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px black;
}

figure.foto-legenda img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

figure.foto-legenda figcaption {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    transition: opacity 1s;
    opacity: 0;  /* unica modificação */
}

figure.foto-legenda:hover figcaption {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure class="foto-legenda">
  <img src="https://www.placecage.com/300/80">
  <figcaption>Oh Nick...</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Comment: A galera etá decifrando o HTML só pelo CSS :D

Comment: Se a pessoa não se ajuda a gente tenta né?! hahaha

Comment: Gente muito obrigada mesmo, o erro era exatamente esse, e eu esqueci de colocar o código em html, mas obrigada pela ajuda mesmo assim.